# Is it possible to accelerate active transport in plant vascular system using some electronic method?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, minerals

I am from electronics background and got an understanding that electrical current affect plant growth. Based on this phenomenon, I got an idea but before I formulate my hypothesis and start experimentation around it, I am looking for some expert opinion on this.

Can we accelerate mineral transport like water movement from root to leaf by some external influences?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Including a summary of what you have learned with references (e.g. to electrical current affecting plant growth) will demonstrate that you have made this effort and provide context for your question. ——— Thank you for taking the [tour], but please also go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks! 